# Are those dangerous idioms/usages in C++ avoidable in C#?

Tags: c#, c++

In this Herb Sutter's article '[Write What You Know, and Know What You Write](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/advice97.htm)', he warns about the dangerous idioms in C++.

```
T& T::operator=( const T& other )
{
  if( this != &other )
  {
    this->~T();
    new (this) T(other);
  }
    return *this;
}
```

Does C# solve this kind of dangerous cases? Is C# a better programming language than C++ in terms of having less dangerous idioms?

Comment: I voted to close this question because it seems to have no useful answers and seems to invite subjective opinions and flamebaits.

Comment: how do you "solve" an idiom? An idiom is a (good) way to do things. It doesn't need solving.

Answer (score 1):

That particular ugliness (I wouldn't call it idiomatic) is not possible in C#, because `operator =` cannot be redefined in C#.  That doesn't make C# better -- times when it would make sense to redefine `=`, you can't so you need a workaround.

Comment: Nor can you invoke a constructor in place. And C# doesn't even have destructors.

Comment: @Tim: absolutely right, but I'm looking at that as "I want to observe DRY when implementing `operator =`" and calling the destructor and constructor are the manifestation of DRY (call the existing implementation instead of duplicating code).  But you don't worry about DRY in `operator =` definitions when there are no `operator =` definitions.